# wired network not working DELL 17R SE

Tags: 12.10, networking, ethernet, realtek

Wired Network not working; it shows connected to network but I get no Internet access..!
System DELL 17R SE

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet|wireless|broadcom)"`

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet|wireless|broadcom)"
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4462]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0578]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Output of `ifconfig -a`

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:50:6a:ae  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:13083 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1229231 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:90241 (90.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:3610 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3610 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:498516 (498.5 KB)  TX bytes:498516 (498.5 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:a6:c8:be:66:62  
      inet addr:192.168.129.101  Bcast:192.168.129.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::86a6:c8ff:febe:6662/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:47879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:46247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:55790608 (55.7 MB)  TX bytes:6349692 (6.3 MB)
```

Comment: Same here on a Dell Inspiron 23 AIO. Wireless works, but not wired. Strange. Config is: 
Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 08)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0548]
 Kernel driver in use: alx
 Kernel modules: alx

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu if there are wireless and wired adapters available during install the wireless adapter is enabled and the wired adapter is disabled by default (in the backend -- turning it on in the Network Manager does nothing).

The only way to turn on the wired adapter is to manually edit /etc/network/interfaces and add a line:

eth0 auto inet

Then use the command:

sudo ifup eth0

to enable the adapter.